# Getting tweets for different hashtags in one call using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, rate-limiting

I want to get popular and recent tweets for different Hash tags, with Tweepy. The solution I have right now is shown below. But this method does a separate call for each hashtag, which is not good in the presence of rate limitations. Is it possible to do this in one call? If so, how?

```
for ht in hash_tags:
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, ht + " -filter:retweets", 
        result_type='mixed', since=date_since, 
        tweet_mode='extended').items(num_of_tweets)
    add_tweets(tweets)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running a `for` loop in which you search for one hashtag at a time, you can run a search which contains many of the hashtags you need using the OR operator from [Twitter's standard search operators](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/rules-and-filtering/search-operators). This is a broader search, and you'll get a mixed bag of results for each hashtag, but it cuts down on the number of requests you make overall.

So add all of your hashtags to a string, and pass this through as your query.

```
#just an example, not the nicest!
    query_string = ""
    for i in hash_tags:
        if i == hash_tags[-1]:
            query_string+=str(i)
        else:
            query_string+=str(i) + " OR "
    tweets = tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query_string + " -filter:retweets", 
    result_type='mixed', since=date_since, 
    tweet_mode='extended').items(num_of_tweets)
add_tweets(tweets)
```

This means your search will be something like `#coolstuff OR #reallycoolstuff OR #evencoolerstuff`. It may be worth increasing the number of items returned when doing this, as the search will be so much more broad.

Keep in mind that there are limits to the size of query you can search with, so you may need to break this down into smaller queries if you've got a lot of hashtags. This may also help you get better results (e.g a more popular hashtag in your query string taking up a lot of your results, so do a separate search for less popular hashtags separately; how you'd measure that though, would be up to you!)

Hope this helps you get started.

Comment: I know about this OR operation and have used it before. But this does not solve my problem as OR wouldn't give results for all the hashtags.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you're inbetween a bit of a rock and a hard place, because you can't get past that rate limit if you must see full results for each hashtag. You'll have to search one at a time. The rate limit is fairly generous, but I guess it depends on what you're using it for/how many hashtags you're searching . 

If you cut it down to two terms per OR you'd double the rate limit; there's a fairly good chance you'll get results for both, just not the full number for each.

Comment: The above is chancing it a bit, and you may end up with skewed data, but I don't believe there's any way to reduce searches in the way you're looking for, at least with the search API. But I do hope you find a way!